# How to display multilines output in a line (Horizontal view) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have made an program that can display many outputs in same textbox in matlab.
The main program do looping and the GUI catch the output and display the outputs in same textbox. But the problem is that the output is displayed in new line.
Iwan to display the output just in one line..
How to do it?
Here is my Gcode to display the output in the GUI.

```
 letterr = ProcessOutput;
 set(handles.text4,'String',letterr);
```

Comment: I need some info: what does ProcessOutput contain? is it just one string or is there some kind of cell-array or similar?

Comment: for ii=1:jml      
        gambar= Iprops(ii).Image;   
         letter{ii}=readLetter(gambar);   
         end

Comment: This is not an aswer to @LuciusDomitiusAhenobarbus ' question...

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
set(handles.text4,'String',strjoin(letterr));
```

depending on the version of matlab you are using, this function is implemented or not. If not, you can get it from here:

[File-exchange: strjoin](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31862-strjoin/content/strjoin/strjoin.m)